# Horizontal Scroll bar to the Toolbar of the Tab Panel

Tags: extjs

I Have a TabPanel to which i am addning dynamically tabs. When the number of the tabs increase they become very small .  Can we have a scrollbar to the toolbar of the tab panel ? 
This my tab panel code :

```
 var centerPanel = new Ext.TabPanel({
                        region: 'center',
                        deferredRender: false,
                        activeTab: 0,
                        autoScroll: true,
                        items: [
                        <if startUrl != "">
                            {
                                title: "${startName}",
                                html: "<iframe src='${startUrl}'  width='100%' height='100%' id='frame_${startName}' frameborder=0 name='name'/>"
                            }
                        </if>
                        ]

});
```

Comment: Which Ext version? In 5 you should automatically get arrows to scroll tabs as here: http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#advanced-tabs

Comment: I am using Extjs 3.4

Answer (score 0):

Try to set "minTabWidth" property of new tabs. The default value is 30 (px). Also set "autoScroll" of TabPanel to true.